# how to run a maven plugin from NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a maven project that uses the javafx-maven-plugin to create an installer. From IntelliJ, I can run the plugin by View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects -> my artifact -> Plugins -> jfx -> jfx:native, and clicking run.

How can I run this plugin from NetBeans IDE 8.0.1?
I did not find out how to see the list available maven plugins to run from NetBeans.

Note: A colleague is using NetBeans and he doest not want to change his IDE. please do not post answers/comments about using or not NetBeans; that is not the question here.

Comment: You should be able to right click on the project -> Custom -> goals. And just type the goal/phase in for the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run goals rather than plugins.

1. Ensure the **Projects** tab is open (press <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>).
2. Right-click the project.
3. Select **Custom → Goals**.
4. Set **Goals** to the name (or phrase) of the goal (plugin).
5. Click **OK** to run the goal.

---

Select the project in the Projects Window(Upper left by default), the Navigator window(bottom left by default) will have the list of goals. Mouse over to see the plugins associated with each one. Right-click to get pop-up on any of the goals to execute them, or execute with modified properties.